# The Expectation of Two Normal Disribution with Zero Mean and One Variance

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value

Assume $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. For $E[XY]$, we have the following:
\begin{equation}
E[XY] = \int XY exp(-X^2 - Y^2) dXdY = \int X exp(-X^2)dX \int Y exp(-Y^2)dY = 0,
\end{equation}

then $E[XY] = 0$. Is this true (there is no condition that $X$ and $Y$ are independent)?

Comment: The joint PDF you gave is that of independent normal random variables so that is implied in what you wrote. Of course, independence would imply zero mean since the mean of the product is the product of the means for the independent case.

Comment: Your joint distribution assumes that $X$ and $Y$ are independent, but you cannot do this without further information.

Comment: In particular, if $P(X=Y)=1$, then $E[XY] =1$.